# Inmobi tracks purchases conversions implementation

Tags: android

I am an android developer,I am using inmobi for ad-tracking in my app which is working fine.Now,i would like to implement "tracks purchases conversions" using inmobi, because through my app i am already doing few subscription activity. I also want to know report of all subscriptions during my application using inmobi.So to implement that, what are the lines of action? Do I need to code something other that what I have coded for ad implementation and if not, then please tell me the steps which I have to follow for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purchase/Subsriptions are known as custom goals in InMobi AdTracker portal.
For tracking purchase/subscriptions,you have to use report Custom Goal API available in InMobi AdTracker SDK. Whenever a purchase or a subscription is completed inside your App, your code should call the API to report a custom goal with a goal name (e.g: purchase) as a string input.

InMobi AdTracker portal shows three counts: Received, Organic, Matched.

For example in case of purchase:
Lets say there are four users of your App: User A, User B, User C and User D

User A clicked on an Ad of your App and then downloaded App from App Store and then made 8 purchases.

User B also clicked on an Ad of your App and then downloaded App from App Store and then made 4 purchases.

User C directly downloaded your App from App Store without clicking on an Ad and then made 3 purchases.

User D also directly downloaded your App from App Store without clicking on an Ad and then made 2 purchases.

In this case:

Received will be equal to 17 i.e. total purchases done in your App by all users.

Organic will show you 5 i.e. total purchases done by users who directly downloaded your App from App Store

Matched will show you 2 i.e. total unique users who made atleast one purchase after downloading your App by clicking on an Ad of your App.In other words,Matched is the total unique purchase making users which you have acquired by running an Ad Campaign for your App on an Ad Network.